# How do platform sites ensure their users do not abuse forwarded user data?

Tags: gdpr

*I am asking this question based upon the specific case of open source software sites, but the concept should probably apply equally to other websites that serve as a "platform" for their users to publish and collaborate.*

I have a number of open source software projects that I develop during my spare time on various large open source software (OSS) websites (think Github, SourceForge, ...).<sup>1</sup>

I sent some GDPR-related inquiries to them to find out about how I can make my project sites GDPR-ready.
Something that appeared to be more or less a consensus was that for the representation of my projects that are displayed in the OSS websites' default layout, they are the "controller" and I am a "processor".

**Now, if I am a processor, wouldn't those controllers have to make me sign a DPA?** I am wondering especially for the case of forwarding notifications about activity related to my projects to my e-mail. Such notifications are likely to contain some kind of personal information (at least the name of a fellow user who did something related to my project).

Bonus question: Does that also mean I am not allowed to set up the e-mail forwarding to any of my existing (mostly Germany-based, if that makes any difference) e-mail accounts, but need to sign up a for a "business-level" (or whatever it's called) e-mail account somewhere so I can have a DPA with the e-mail provider?<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>: These websites are based in the U.S. This is not generally my preference, but there simply seems to be no comparable website for such services anywhere else.

<sup>2</sup>: It's indeed still [unclear](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/28955/according-to-gdpr-do-i-need-a-contract-for-processing-on-behalf-with-my-e-mail) whether an e-mail provider counts as a processor for which a DPA is needed. If it turns out it does not, the second part of the question is a non-issue.

Comment: Do you just develop software (ie. making available for others to download), or do you also host your own server where the software runs?

Comment: @wimh: Just the former.

Comment: I think you are not the processer, but you might be [joint controllers](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-26-gdpr/) based on C-210/16. I have to reread that judgement, maybe I'll answer tomorrow.

Comment: @wimh: That is an interesting interpretation. However, wouldn't that imply that I have to link to a privacy policy of my own, even on pages whose content and layout I cannot influence?